# Default date format in jstl expression

Tags: java, jstl, expression

I have already visited posts below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250585/how-to-set-date-pattern-date-format-for-an-entire-application

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281380/format-date-with-fmtformatdate-jsp

Isn't there a way through which I can somehow define default date format ..so that I need not to format in to entire application.

I mean I don't want to use formatter again and again ...any idea on same?

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you will enter the date by a field (input type text) use a javascript calendar and fixe the format inside the script.

Comment: no I need to show it ... It wont use calander ... I need to change jstl's default

Answer (score 0):

Create one utility class like this .

```
public class DateUtil {
    public static final String BY_DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";
}
```

And then in your jsp page do like this.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${yourBean.date}" pattern="<%=DateUtil.BY_DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT %>" />
```